# Apache Drill querying mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, apache-drill

I am trying to query a mongodb collection with schema changes using apache drill, however I keep encountering this error

> IllegalArgumentException: You tried to write a BigInt type when you are using a ValueWriter of type NullableIntWriterImpl.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Sample Data in the mongo collection is:

_id : 4563  string
code: 567438 string
amount: 228218 int32
indicator : G string

The drill query is: `select * from collection_name`

Comment: mention sample data in the mongodb collection and drill query tried.

Comment: also share your MongoDB and Drill version

Answer (score 3):

Corrupted JSON records in MongoDB can cause this.

You can handle this using `exec.enable_union_type` option.

Fire query:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET `exec.enable_union_type` = true;
```

Or go to http://localhost:8047/options (*assuming drill is running on local machine replace with IP if not*)

And change `exec.enable_union_type` to **true**.

This issue is explained in details at : http://www.dremio.com/blog/finding-corrupt-json-records-in-mongodb/